# nginx lua simple WAF

Tags: nginx, lua

how to create a simplest WAF using nginx-lua? for example i want to block POST request (form-data) sent to /customer/account/createpost which has 'firstname' longer than 20 character or containing URL.

I tried resty.post but i'm stuck at attempt to index local m ( nil value) error.

Comment: Please provide more context. Nginx config and Lay code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reference the open source implementation of WAF using nginx lua: [link](https://github.com/loveshell/ngx_lua_waf)

Even though the readme.txt is in Chinese, I believe it is a relatively simple example to learn.